# Shopware 6 Plugin - text snippet not deleted on uninstall plugin - order custom field label

Tags: custom-fields, shopware6

We created custom fields within our plugin for orders and for products.
Shopware creates text snippets for the custom fields labels.
These should be removed when uninstalling the plugin.

It works for the products custom field.

```
...
'customFields' => [
    [
        'name' => 'product_custom_field_name_dummy',
        'type' => CustomFieldTypes::BOOL,
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'componentName' => 'sw-field',
            'customFieldType' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => [
                self::GER_ISO => 'Label GER',
                self::EN_ISO => 'Label EN',
                Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => 'Label EN',
            ]
        ],
    ]
],
'relations' => [
    [
        'entityName' => ProductDefinition::ENTITY_NAME,
    ],
],
...
```

But not for the orders custom fields.

```
...
'customFields' => [
    [
        'name' => 'order_custom_field_name_dummy_one',
        'type' => CustomFieldTypes::TEXT,
        'config' => [
            'customFieldType' => CustomFieldTypes::TEXT,
            'label' => [
                self::GER_ISO => 'Order Label GER',
                self::EN_ISO => 'Order Label EN',
                Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => 'Order Label EN',
            ]
        ],
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'order_custom_field_name_dummy_two',
        'type' => CustomFieldTypes::SELECT,
        'config' => [
            'customFieldType' => CustomFieldTypes::SELECT,
            'componentName' => 'sw-single-select',
            'label' => [
                self::GER_ISO => 'Order Label GER 2',
                self::EN_ISO => 'Order Label EN 2',
                Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => 'Order Label EN 2',
            ],
            'options' => [
                ...
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'order_custom_field_name_dummy_three',
        'type' => CustomFieldTypes::DATETIME,
        'config' => [
            'customFieldType' => CustomFieldTypes::DATETIME,
            'label' => [
                self::GER_ISO => 'Order Label GER 3',
                self::EN_ISO => 'Order Label EN 3',
                Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => 'Order Label EN 3',
            ]
        ],
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'order_custom_field_name_dummy_four',
        'type' => CustomFieldTypes::SELECT,
        'config' => [
            'customFieldType' => CustomFieldTypes::SELECT,
            'componentName' => 'sw-single-select',
            'label' => [
                self::GER_ISO => 'Order Label GER 4',
                self::EN_ISO => 'Order Label EN 4',
                Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => 'Order Label EN 4',
            ],
            'options' => [
                ...
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
'relations' => [
    [
        'entityName' => OrderDefinition::ENTITY_NAME,
    ],
],
...
```

Is this a problem Shopware has with order custom fields or did we possibly make a mistake when creating the order custom fields?

**Edit:**
The custom fields are created on install method und removed on uninstall method inside the plugin via the CustomFieldSetRepository.

**Edit:**
This is how we delete the custom fields on uninstall:

```
public function uninstallCustomFieldSet() {
    $customFieldSet = $this->getCustomFieldSet(self::CUSTOM_FIELD_SET_NAME);
    if ($customFieldSet instanceof CustomFieldSetEntity) {
        $this->customFieldSetRepository->delete([['id' => $customFieldSet->getId()]], $this->context);
    }
}

protected function getCustomFieldSet(string $customFieldSetName): ?CustomFieldSetEntity {
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $customFieldSetName));
    $criteria->addAssociation('customFields');
    $criteria->addAssociation('relations');
    $customFieldSet = $this->customFieldSetRepository->search($criteria, $this->context)->first();

    if ($customFieldSet instanceof CustomFieldSetEntity) {
        return $customFieldSet;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the custom fields? Inside the Plugin via the repository service or over the API?

Comment: Inside the plugin via CustomFieldSetRepository.

Comment: You should add code to the `uninstall` method of your Plugin class that removes your custom field during plugin uninstalling.

Comment: Yes that is my point. While removing those custom fields on uninstall, the text snippets of order custom fields are not being removed.

Comment: As @ValeriiPravoslavnyi already pointed out, you should remove the custom fields manually during `uninstall` of your plugin. I'm not sure i understand the point that the text snippets are not removed. Where do the text snippets show up? As the values for the labels are only stored in the DB, so after removing the custom fields the values should be gone too.

Comment: Shopware has criticized that we do not properly remove text snippets when installing the plugin. We checked this and noticed that text snippets are automatically created for the labels of the custom fields and these are not removed when we remove the custom fields. They look like this: customFields.custom_field_name

Comment: @Tanmar could you please share a code on how you exactly delete custom fields?

Comment: I see that Shopware has a listener for `custom_field.deleted` event, but you delete CustomFieldSet and not fields itself. So looks like you need to delete fields first to trigger snippet deletion.

Comment: @Valerio8787 thanks for the hint. I have adjusted the code and deleted custom fields first, via the custom field repository (before deleting the set). Unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Fyi. Shopware has confirmed that this is a core bug.

Comment: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-24023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author mentions that Shopware 6 confirms that it's a bug.

I am creating an answer to this question even though it was already answered in the comments so that it can be accepted & this question resolved.